# Is it possible to change the title of "Quick Post" dashboard widgets?

Tags: control-panel, dashboard-widgets

For this particular build the client will frequently be creating 3 similar, but unique, types of content all housed in the same section which differ by a Content Type. When creating "quick post" widgets for the dashboard, each widget is currently given the same name despite the corresponding Entry Type. I don't necessarily need granular control over the title, but a way to provide additional context to the administrators would be nice.

Comment: I believe the answer to this is "no" but I wanted to raise the issue just incase.

Comment: Did it work the plugin?

Comment: This should definitely be something that one should be able to do without having to rely on a JS hack. Maybe they'll update the widget!

Comment: I haven't tried the plugin yet. I want to use that as a last resort. It seems like a simple solution to implement but I don't want to rely on JS if I don't have to.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use this [Control Panel JS plugin](https://github.com/lindseydiloreto/craft-cpjs/) to change the info.

Just copy the `cpjs` folder in the `craft/plugins/` folder and the plugin should appear in `Settings->Plugins`. Install it and add your code in the textarea displayed at the bottom.

Now with your title:

In the dashboard, each widget has an ID like `widget1`, `widget2`, etc; get it with the dev tools.

Then try the following code changing the corresponding widget number:

`document.getElementById("widget1").childNodes[3].innerHTML = "new_title";`